# How to properly return a string constant from an expression?

Tags: tcl

Let's say I have the following:

```
proc one_or_other {v1 v2} {
    if {[expr {round(rand())}]} {
        expr {$v1}
    } else {
        expr {$v2}
    }
}
```

It randomly returns one of two values `$v1` or `$v2`. Pretty simple. And it works properly until you give it a string like "01232", which can be interpreted as an octal number by `expr`. So,`one_or_other 1234 01232` gives you `666` half the time.

If I want this function to give me exactly one of the two strings that I passed it (e.g. it gives me "1234" or "01232"), what do I replace `expr {$v1}` with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you want a general string constant as the result of a command, that command had better not be `expr`. The issue is that `expr` is *defined* to convert its result to canonical numerical form if possible, even if there are no other operations.

This means that if `x` is set to `0x123`, I'd *always* expect `expr {$x}` to produce `291`.

---

Let's peel back the hood a bit, and look at the bytecode disassembly for `expr {$x}`:

```
% tcl::unsupported::disassemble script {expr {$x}}
ByteCode 0x0x7f9683041b10, refCt 1, epoch 17, interp 0x0x7f9683024410 (epoch 17)
  Source "expr {$x}"
  Cmds 1, src 9, inst 5, litObjs 1, aux 0, stkDepth 1, code/src 0.00
  Commands 1:
      1: pc 0-3, src 0-8
  Command 1: "expr {$x}"
    (0) push1 0     # "x"
    (2) loadStk 
    (3) tryCvtToNumeric 
    (4) done
```

There's a bunch of stuff we can ignore, but the opcodes at the end are a push of a constant (which is the name of the variable) onto the operand stack, a read of a variable named on the operand stack (in combination with the previous op, this does `$x`), a `tryCvtToNumeric` (more about in a moment), and a `done` to mark the end of this little script.

So what is the `tryCvtToNumeric` doing? It's implementing the result semantics of `expr`, and it's put in there always (except when the compiler can prove it isn't required, which is actually true for most code). There isn't a way to turn this off.

Disassembling your procedure shows it up. (I'll skip the bits we can ignore here.)

```
(0) push1 0     # "tcl::mathfunc::round"
(2) push1 1     # "tcl::mathfunc::rand"
(4) invokeStk1 1 
(6) invokeStk1 2 
(8) nop 
(9) nop 
(10) jumpFalse1 +16     # pc 26
(12) startCommand +12 1     # next cmd at pc 24, 1 cmds start here
(21) loadScalar1 %v0    # var "v1"
(23) tryCvtToNumeric 
(24) jump1 +14  # pc 38
(26) startCommand +12 1     # next cmd at pc 38, 1 cmds start here
(35) loadScalar1 %v1    # var "v2"
(37) tryCvtToNumeric 
(38) done
```

As you can see, there are `tryCvtToNumeric` instances in there; your code has transforms in it. (Also note in passing that the code is using more efficient local variable table ops to read variables. That's good.)

---

When you need a general string result, use other standard Tcl commands instead. In particular, `set x` (i.e., *one* argument) is a command that is like `$x`, `string cat 0x123` is a command that produces a literal string `0x123`, and the result of `if` (often ignored) is the result of the script in the branch that was taken. Your actual script then becomes (without the extra `expr`s):

```
proc one_or_other {v1 v2} {
    if {round(rand())} {
        set v1
    } else {
        set v2
    }
}
```

Let's check by disassembling:

```
(0) push1 0     # "tcl::mathfunc::round"
(2) push1 1     # "tcl::mathfunc::rand"
(4) invokeStk1 1 
(6) invokeStk1 2 
(8) nop 
(9) jumpFalse1 +15  # pc 24
(11) startCommand +11 1     # next cmd at pc 22, 1 cmds start here
(20) loadScalar1 %v0    # var "v1"
(22) jump1 +13  # pc 35
(24) startCommand +11 1     # next cmd at pc 35, 1 cmds start here
(33) loadScalar1 %v1    # var "v2"
(35) done
```

That's the same code… except without the `tryCvtToNumeric` ops that were causing you trouble. (Also one less no-op.)

Personally, I'd use this slightly more efficient version instead:

```
proc one_or_other {v1 v2} {
    if {rand() < 0.5} {
        return $v1
    } else {
        return $v2
    }
}
```

I prefer to use explicit `return`s, and to avoid function calls I don't need.

Comment: Thanks. And what if I want to return a constant value that could be "01232" ?

Comment: For completeness, you may want to use the `if-else` expression variant: `expr {rand() < 0.5 ? $v1 : $v2}`

Comment: As for values that could be interpreted as octals, it is safer to use an explicit `if` command call (as Donal showed). `expr` will accidentally interpret anything looking like an octal as such. If you want to stick with `expr`, then you will have to sanitize the values referenced by `v1` and `v2`, e.g. using [`scan %d`](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tcl+and+octal+numbers), for instance.